# How to store a file in HttpSessionListener Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

How to store a file in HttpSessionListener.

[image]

When i taping on Upload link selected file will store in session. If i tap on Send button all data in form will submit. If i not session will be destroy.

Comment: How did you implement it?

Comment: @Alfabravo i have image in my question.

Comment: Use Session.setAttribute(), Refer https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute